# 150k words text file is 0.8mb where realm db size is 18mb

Tags: android, realm

I am inserting 150000 objects in realm db. Object has only one property which is string.
At the same time I am creating a string builder with new line for each string
and finally writing it into a text file.

At the end text file size is 0.8mb. Where realm db size is 18mb. What is the cause for it. How to minimize realm db size. Can you please helm me. Here is the realm insertion code

```
private void insertWord() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

    RealmConf conf = RealmConf.getInstance(true);
    int i = 0;
    RealmUtils.startTransaction(conf);


    while (i < 150000) {
        i++;
        String word = "Word:" + i;
        EB eb = new EB(word);
        builder.append(word+"\n");

        RealmUtils.saveWord(eb, conf);
        Log.i("word check" + i++, "seelog:" + word);
    }
    RealmUtils.commitTransaction(conf);
    writeStringIntoFile(builder.toString(),0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, for science:

```
private void insertWord() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

    RealmConf conf = RealmConf.getInstance(true);
    int i = 0;
    int batchCount = 0;


    while (i < 150000) {
        if(batchCount == 0) {
            RealmUtils.startTransaction(conf);
        }
        batchCount++
        i++;
        String word = "Word:" + i;
        EB eb = new EB(word);
        builder.append(word+"\n");

        RealmUtils.saveWord(eb, conf);
        Log.i("word check" + i++, "seelog:" + word);
        if(batchCount == 3000) {
            RealmUtils.commitTransaction(conf);
            batchCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if(batchCount != 0) {
        RealmUtils.commitTransaction(conf);
    }
    writeStringIntoFile(builder.toString(),0);
}
```

Comment: Hello, My words ar Just "Word1","Word2" ...Word150000
What should be the minimum optimum size should be. Assuming that i used all your science along with close, compact whatever thing possible. I actually need ans from Realm People as i am unable to get it less than 18mb

Comment: after I set `compactOnLaunch(() -> {return true;})` on my configuration, it decreased file size to 3 MB ~ you have to close Realm instance before calling `compact`, check if it returned true or false

Comment: Close Realm before compact works. Anyway, my db size is now 1.3 mb without using your science. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you forgot to call `Realm.close()`.
Refer to this document for more details.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq

> Large Realm file size You should expect a Realm database to take less
>   space on disk than an equivalent SQLite database, but in order to give
>   you a consistent view of your data, Realm operates on multiple
>   versions of a Realm. This can cause the Realm file to grow
>   disproportionately if the difference between the oldest and newest
>   version of data grows too big.
>
> Realm will automatically remove the older versions of data if they are
>   not being used anymore, but the actual file size will not decrease.
>   The extra space will be reused by future writes.
>
> If needed, the extra space can be removed by compacting the Realm
>   file. This can either be done manually or automatically when opening
>   the Realm for the first time.
>
> If you are experiencing an unexpected file size growth, it is usally
>   happening for one of two reasons:
>
> 1) You open a Realm on a background thread and forget to close it
>   again.
>
> This will cause Realm to retain a reference to the data on the
>   background thread and is the most common cause for Realm file size
>   issues. The solution is to make sure to correctly close your Realm
>   instance. Read more here and here. Realm will detect if you forgot to
>   close a Realm instance correctly and print a warning in Logcat.
>   Threads with loopers, like the UI thread, do not have this problem.
>
> 2) You read some data from a Realm and then block the thread on a
>   long-running operation while writing many times to the Realm on other
>   threads.
>
> This will cause Realm to create many intermediate versions that needs
>   to be tracked. Avoiding this scenario is a bit more tricky, but can
>   usually be done by either either batching the writes or avoiding
>   having the Realm open while otherwise blocking the background thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I close the realm. Still size is showing 18mb.